# SQLite rawQuery with multiple WHERE clauses

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite, where-clause

I have retrieved 2 values through the putExtra and getStringExtra method in another class. BOth these values are correct. I need to use these 2 values in my SQL query:

```
final Cursor cursor = sdb.rawQuery("SELECT match_player_name FROM match_response WHERE match_date=? AND " +
            "match_response =?"+new String [] {String.valueOf(date),String.valueOf(response)}, null);
```

I am unfamiliar using rawQuery with more than 1 condition. Have I the correct syntax? I have a record in my `SQLite` database satisfying this condition.

Comment: `Have I the correct syntax?` **NO**. The string array must be in place of `null`

Answer (score 2):

This is an example:

```java
Cursor cur = database.rawQuery("select name from Table where ID=? and SubCategoryID=?",
                               new String [] {String1,String2});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public Cursor getMachineServices(){    
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select row1, from maquina where something = x AND somethingelse = y", new String[]{});
            return c;

}
```

Then on your activity where you want to display it you must do:

```
Database db;

 db = new Database(yourActivity);
            Cursor c = db.getMachineServices);

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {

                do {




          String machines
 c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("row1"));
                       //you can use the variable machines where you want


                    } while (c.moveToNext());

                }
```